# Why are some nuget package references required by applications?

Tags: c#, nuget

I have a question that has been bothering me for awhile. I ran across this problem a few years back when I was dealing with writing a generic logging wrapper around some hosted provider instances using log4net.

The idea was simple enough, I wanted to write a logging and metrics that hid all the implementation in a separate visual studio project so when you wanted to add any telemetry support to another application you could just include the project, new up an instance of the logger and start logging using generic calls. If you ever switched providers or tweak logging settings, it wouldn't require any changes to the host applications.

This creates a strong decoupling point, where the main application used an interface in a logging class library, but would know nothing about the packages or providers that the logging class library was using to do the real work.

When I did this and tried out using Loggly's nuget package and log4net, I found that the calling application had to have a ref to the nuget package or else the dependent assembly would not be copied to the build directory. At the time I just wrote this off as something odd that they Loggly engineers were doing. But I have since encountered the same behavior in some, but not all other packages. (DogstatsD doesn't have a problem, Raygun does, etc..)

I have noticed that some nuget packages in assemblies are automatically copied into the parent output directory, but when I look for the setting that controls this, I cannot find it.

I have written dozens of class libraries over the years, and I have never had a problem with 'chained dependency assemblies (a refs b, b refs c, etc.) resolving when I build. It only seems to be some nuget packages that are a problem.

How do I force nuget packages referenced by a class library project to copy into the build directory without an explicit reference in the application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured this one out.

This is a problem only for the Log4Net & Loggly wrapper assembly combo in particular because it is referenced entirely at runtime. Log4net loads up its required log appenders at runtime, and because .net doesn't see a ref to the assembly at build time, it assumes that it isn't being used and omits copying the required assembly to the bin directory. The solution when you know this is simple, just write an empty dummy method in the referenced library that you can call in the main application. This will cause .net to include the assembly in the build.

While this problem is specific to the Log4net library, it could occur anywhere that you are using an assembly that is only used with runtime reflection.